# SpreeCommerce: Mark order as pending

Tags: spree

SpreeCommerce has an order overview, where it's possible to see all the orders and the states. Each day we open the order overview, and find the completed orders, pack them and ship them to the customer.

However, sometimes we don't have the goods for an order in stock, and want to mark the order as "pending", so we don't open the order each day by mistake.

What's the best way in SpreeCommerce to mark an order as "pending", so we only have to check the pending orders, when we get a new shipment of goods from our supplier?

It would be great, if we could use the state property, because SpreeCommerce allows us to filter orders by their state.

Answer (score 1):

Spree supports inventory tracking as described here:

http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/inventory.html

This will allow you to flag a shipment as being backordered:

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/v2.2.1/core/app/models/spree/shipment.rb#L79-L81

if any of its inventory units are backordered.  An order is considered backordered if any of its shipments are considered backordered:

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/order.rb#L193-L195

Your best bets for putting an order in to a back ordered state would be:

1. Turn on inventory tracking in Spree and keep it up to date through synchronization or manual audits
2. Extend Spree to override what it means for shipment to be considered backordered and allow this to be set and unset by administrators as stock levels change

Which solution you should choose depends a great deal upon the specifics of your store and how you manage inventory.  The specifics of your implementation could make either solution very easy, or very difficult.